# How to call json controller with ajax without redirect to page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to call a MVC controller with ajax like this

```
function programare() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Programeaza")",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name : $("#name").val()
            , surnume : $("#surnume").val()            
        },
        error: function (response) {
            if (!response.Success)
               alert("Server error.");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (!response.Success)
                       alert("Form Error.");
        }
    });
}
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
    public JsonResult Programeaza(ProgramareModel input) {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.name)){
            return Json(new {Success = false});
                    }

        return Json("OK");
    }
```

After calling the controller I'm redirected to `Programare/Programeaza` page that display "OK" or {"Success":false} instead of execute the success or error function from ajax.

I just want to display the message "OK" or "Server error" as an alert and stay on the same page.

EDIT:  if I add

```
        async: false,
```

to ajax, the success function is called and the "OK" message is displayed, but after that it still redirect to the page displaying the Json content.

How should I make it stop after the alert message?

```
    $(function () {
        $("#programare").click(programare); 
    });
```

html:

```
    <button type="submit" id="programare">Programeaza</button>
```

Comment: When are you invoking the ajax call, on form submit, button click etc?

Comment: I'm invoking the ajax method on button click

Comment: Show the code which is invoking the ajax call.

Comment: $(function () {

  $("#programare").click(programare);
 });
                <button type="submit" id="programare">Programeaza</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your jquery in following way -

```
<script>
    function Click() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Programeaza")",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                name: $("#name").val()
            , surname: $("#surname").val()
            },
            error: function (response) {
                if (!response.Success)
                    alert("Server error.");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 'OK')
                    alert(response);
                else
                    alert(response.Success);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

and HTML is going to be -

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
<input type="button" onclick="Click()" value="Click"/>
```

Serverside controller code is -

```
public class jsonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult Programeaza(ProgramareModel input)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.name))
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false });
        }

        return Json("OK");
    }
}

public class ProgramareModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

When you run the application, you have following screen -

[image]

When incoked with NO inputs in the form, you get - **false**

When inputs were there, then you get **OK** in the alert.

**And there is no REDIRECTION**

Comment: @user3234688 if my post helps, can you please mark it as answer, that would help others to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

Json Ajax code

```
  $.post("/BindInventory/CheckItem", { input: name }, function (result) {
     alert(reselt);
  });
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult Programeaza(ProgramareModel input) {
    var str ="OK";
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.name)){
        return Json(new {Success = false});
                }

    return JsonResult(str, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the default behavior of the form submit. Change your code the next way:

```
function programare() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Programeaza")",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name : $("#name").val()
            , surnume : $("#surnume").val()            
        },
        error: function (response) {
            if (!response.Success)
               alert("Server error.");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (!response.Success)
                       alert("Form Error.");
        }
    });
    return false; // add this line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The document sees that you are submitting a form, which by default is a synchronous action, and causes a new page-load.

You need to handle the click event like this:

```
$('#programare').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    programare();
}
```