# How to pass a model to controller through ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. How to pass a model to controller through Ajax? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348813/how-to-call-json-controller-with-ajax-without-redirect-to-page), but I was confused and have tried with my code shown below, but without any luck. Any help is appreciated!
Many thanks in advance.

This is my Ajax calls to controller:

```
const fd = new FormData($('#form-data')[0]);

const data = {};
fd.forEach((value, key) => (data[key] = value));

console.log(data);

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/User/Update_Me/',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result)
            {
               alert('horeee');
            },
            error: function (result)
            { 
               alert('error here');
            }
```

And this is my `UserController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/User/Update_Me")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Update_Me(Views.User.Data data)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(data);

    // Starts process here ...
}
```

Comment: You need to look at parameter binding. [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) should help you out on that. I believe you are missing a `[FromBody]` binding in your controller action. `public IActionResult Update_Me([FromBody] Views.User.Data data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your js code, The type of data is `object`, So you need to change your ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/User/Update_Me/',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result)
            {
               alert('horeee');
            },
            error: function (result)
            { 
               alert('error here');
            }
})
```

Then in action, You also need to add `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
public IActionResult Update_Me([FromBody]Views.User.Data data)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(data);

    // Starts process here ...
}
```